# Redefining anonymous types in external lib - dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c

In a function with a single va_list arg, I'm trying to attribute a list of variables as per an externally defined (header file) struct wifi_ap_record_t (other values omitted for clarity).

The type definition in "wifi_ap_record_t_header_location.h" is as follows, this is an external library I'm unable to edit:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t ssid[33];                     /**< SSID of AP */

} wifi_ap_record_t;
```

On compilation I'm getting the following error:
`error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'const struct wifi_ap_record_t'` which is upset about the `p->ssid` pointer. I've tried redefining the typedef with and without the pointer as well as defining a blank `wifi_ap_record` variable of type `wifi_ap_record_t`.

Code as below, what is missing here?

```
#include "wifi_ap_record_t_header_location.h"

typedef struct wifi_ap_record_t* wifi_ap_record;

void function(va_list *ap) {
  const struct wifi_ap_record_t *p = va_arg(*ap, const struct wifi_ap_record *);
  printf("ssid: %s", p->ssid;
}
```

Comment: `#include "wifi_ap_record_t_header_location.h"`? (quotes)

Comment: Please correct the syntax of your code.

Comment: Corrected, not the issue.

Comment: This is a good question though

Answer (score 2):

After the typedef in the external library, the name of the type is `wifi_ap_record_t`, not `struct wifi_ap_record_t`.

Names that start with `struct` is a separate space, but typedef-ed names are not in it, even if they refer to a struct type.

There should be no `struct` keyword in your own code. A pointer to this struct will have the type `wifi_ap_record_t*`, not `struct wifi_ap_record_t*`. You don't need your own typedef.

Comment: This can solve your question. I missed that part, thans @Thomas.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with this; what should to typedef look like - should it even be there?

Answer (score 2):

this is an example why pointers **should not** be typedefed

1. You have a bunch of another warnings, which you ignore and this is wrong.
2. Do not hide pointers in typedefs - even if this 5 lines example you have already lost lost control what is the pointer and what is not (and you have `**` pointer there).

This is much more clearer, readable and compiles OK

```
  wifi_ap_record_t *p = va_arg(*ap, wifi_ap_record_t *);
  printf("ssid: %s", p ->ssid);
```

Comment: I don't think he has a pointer to pointer? He (tries to) define the type `wifi_ap_record`, which is a pointer, but then that type isn't used. (But I do agree that pointers should not be typedefed.)

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy `wifi_ap_record *` and `wifi_ap_record` is a pointer itself. So another victim of the typedef pointer trap.

Comment: Ah, yes, in the macro. I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alex, define your structure like this:

```
struct wifi_ap_record_t{
    uint8_t ssid[33];                     /**< SSID of AP */

};
```

It seems like you have defined a structure but without any name. Also you have created a object out of that.

In case it is an external structure, check if that structure is defined under any other structure. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376494/what-are-the-benefits-of-unnamed-structs-unions-in-c) question for more information.

Finally, as the other answer and comment says, you should remove the `struct` word while defining the object. So, it will become:

`typedef wifi_ap_record_t* wifi_ap_record;`

Similarly fix other such instances.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't as that's how it's defined in an external library

Comment: @AlexTurner: "*I can't as that's how it's defined in an external library*" Then change this `const struct wifi_ap_record_t *p` to be `const wifi_ap_record_t *p`.

Comment: "*`typedef wifi_ap_record_t* wifi_ap_record;`*" hiding a pointer-type behind a typedef mostly never is a good idea.