# Padding issue? (C / GCC)

Tags: c, gcc

I'm attempting to unify an ARM project's (specifically, the i.MX27 CPU running Linux 2.6.33.3, being compiled with GCC 4.3.2) approach to its SQLite interactions. As part of that, I've created a structure with a union that gets used to hold values to be bound to prepared statements.

```
#define SQLITE_DATA_CHARACTER_STRING_MAX 1024

typedef struct
{
    int data_type;
    union
    {
        int integer;
        double floating_point;
        unsigned char character_string[SQLITE_DATA_CHARACTER_STRING_MAX];
    };
}sqlite_data;
```

Originally, this was `int`, `float`, `char`. I wanted to use `long long`, `double`, and `char`. However, that seems to cause a problem. As typed above, the following code produces predictable output:

```
int data_fields = 15;
int data_fields_index = 0;
sqlite_data data[data_fields];

LogMsg(LOG_INFO, "%s: Assigning", __FUNCTION__);

for(data_fields_index = 0; data_fields_index < data_fields; data_fields_index++)
{
    data[data_fields_index].data_type = (100 + data_fields_index);
    data[data_fields_index].integer = (1000 + data_fields_index);
    LogMsg(LOG_INFO, "%s: data[%d] - %d; type - %d", __FUNCTION__, data_fields_index, data[data_fields_index].integer, data[data_fields_index].data_type);
}
```

The output of which is this:

```
 Assigning
 data[0] - 1000; type - 100
 data[1] - 1001; type - 101
 data[2] - 1002; type - 102
 data[3] - 1003; type - 103
 data[4] - 1004; type - 104
 data[5] - 1005; type - 105
 data[6] - 1006; type - 106
 data[7] - 1007; type - 107
 data[8] - 1008; type - 108
 data[9] - 1009; type - 109
 data[10] - 1010; type - 110
 data[11] - 1011; type - 111
 data[12] - 1012; type - 112
 data[13] - 1013; type - 113
 data[14] - 1014; type - 114
```

However, if I make only one change (giving `integer` the type `long long`) it all falls apart. So, the following change:

```
typedef struct
{
    int data_type;
    union
    {
        long long integer;
        double floating_point;
        unsigned char character_string[SQLITE_DATA_CHARACTER_STRING_MAX];
    };
}sqlite_data;
```

Produces this ouput:

```
Assigning
data[0] - 1000; type - 0
data[1] - 1001; type - 0
data[2] - 1002; type - 0
data[3] - 1003; type - 0
data[4] - 1004; type - 0
data[5] - 1005; type - 0
data[6] - 1006; type - 0
data[7] - 1007; type - 0
data[8] - 1008; type - 0
data[9] - 1009; type - 0
data[10] - 1010; type - 0
data[11] - 1011; type - 0
data[12] - 1012; type - 0
data[13] - 1013; type - 0
data[14] - 1014; type - 0
```

I've tried deunionizing them, using `#pragma pack(6)`, and putting that array on the heap, all with identical results: `int` works, `long long` doesn't.

What's going on here?

Comment: Side note, unless you are targeting C11, [unnamed unions are not portable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228104/anonymous-union-within-struct-not-in-c99). Got bit last week when porting a custom protocol to Windows.

Comment: You can also print out the address of the struct to see if the step changes with the declaration change. That would let you see the padding effect directly.

Comment: Unnamed unions aren't standards-compliant, but they are extremely portable. I'm not aware of any mainstream compiler that doesn't support them as an extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not telling `printf()` to expect a `long long`. Use `%lld` in your format string instead of `%d`.

Comment: The `long long` is printing out fine. It's `int type` that's printing out as zero.

Comment: @musasabi But maybe you are messing up your stack with the wrong specifier (it causes undefined behavior). So use `%lld` for printing `long long`.

Comment: I added some visualization of what is likely happening which I hope helps you understand (this is still undefined behavior so we can't be 100% sure that what I show is happening). Sneftel and H2CO3 are correct.

Answer (score 4):

Sneftel is absolutely correct. The problem is that you are not specifying `long long` which results in undefined behavior. To help you visualize picture the following:

```
"%s: data[%d] - %d; type - %d"

%s - [✓] __FUNCTION__ is a valid string.
%d - [✓] data_fields_index is an int
%d - [x] data[data_fields_index].integer is a long long, this will only read 
          the first 4 bytes of an 8 byte integer.
%d - [x] this is likely reading the last 4 bytes of 
          data[data_fields_index].integer which will be 0 for smaller numbers 
          on a little endian architecture.
```

So as a long long 1000 will be stored in memory in little endian as:

```
[0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00]
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      first %d          second %d
```

Changing the format to `"%s: data[%d] - %lld; type - %d" will fix this.`

Comment: Exactly. The endianness of the platform is important here, as is the underlying ABI. The takeaway is "undefined behavior can look like anything -- it's not localized".

Comment: I want to thank you both for being exactly correct _and_ so detailed. =) Upvoted, though I can only select one answer. <3 to all. =D