# Struct with union: structure has no member named

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have the following structures:

```
struct sched_param {
    union {
        int sched_priority;
        struct lshort_sched_param lshort_params;
    };
};

struct lshort_sched_param {
    int requested_time;
    int level;
};
```

Whenever I make a `sched_param param1` structure and try to update the `param1.sched_priority` field I get the message written in the topic.

```
struct sched_param param1;
param1.sched_priority = 1;
```

But, whenever I make a `sched_param param2` and try to update the `param2.lshort_params.level` it works good.

```
struct sched_param param2;
param2.lshort_params.level= 1;
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: you need to give the union an identifier, so it can be referred to.

Comment: This is a struct given to us in an homework assignment, so I cant give a name to the union. Is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 3):

It is because the version of the gcc compiler you are using does not support **unnamed union**. See this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110478/gcc-inconsistent-compilation-error-has-no-member-named)

Answer (score 3):

Your union should have a name, for instance

```
struct sched_param {
    union {
        int sched_priority;
        struct lshort_sched_param lshort_params;
    } union_member_name;
};
```

and then you can use `param1.union_member_name.sched_priority`

Comment: This is a struct given to us in an homework assignment, so I cant give a name to the union. Is there any other solution ?

Comment: @helloV already gave you a solution.