# Can't set union values

Tags: c, unions

I have this code

```
union u_value {
    int i_value;
    long l_value;
    float f_value;
    double d_value;
    char *cp_value;
    int type;
};

union u_value create_int_value(int value) {
    union u_value val;
    val.i_value = value;
    val.type = INT;

    printf("Inside: %d, %d\n", value, val.i_value);

    return val;
}
```

The problem is that I can't set values inside union.

For example:

```
union u_value val = create_int_value(123);
printf("%d\n", val.i_value);
```

will print `0`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `type` is itself a member of the union. Setting it overwrites whatever value you set previously. If you are trying to implement a tagged union, you will need a `struct` for that, of which one member is a union and **another separate member** is the type tag.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I didn't know that. Thank you! Feel so stupid now

Comment: well, you don't have to *know* anything special for this. why would the `type` field be special? it's just another member of the union. It shares storage with all of the other members. You need to **understand** what a union is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've specified the `type` member as part of the union, which of course will cause its memory to collide with the rest of the fields.

To create a ["tagged union"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), you must separate the tag from the union. Something like:

```
struct u_value {
    int type;
    union {
      int i_value;
      long l_value;
      float f_value;
      double d_value;
      char *cp_value;
    } value;
};
```

Then you can use:

```
u_value x;
x.type = INT;
x.value.i_value = 4711;
```

From [C11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228104/anonymous-union-within-struct-not-in-c99) you can make the inner `union` anonymous, which is handy.

Comment: Most compilers will also allow nifty anonymous structs so you can access `x.i_value` directly :)

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess, `INT` is defined as 0..? You're setting `i_value` first to 123, and then setting `type` which, because it's a union is overwriting `i_value`.

What you need to do is split the type out from the union

```
union u_value 
{
    int i_value;
    long l_value;
    float f_value;
    double d_value;
    char *cp_value;
};

struct my_type
{
  union u_value value;
  int type;
};

struct my_type create_int_value(int value) {
    struct my_type val;
    val.value.i_value = value;
    val.type = INT;

    printf("Inside: %d, %d\n", value, val.value.i_value);

    return val;
}
```

Now the type wont overwrite the value.