# Keil Compiler Warning: anonymous unions are a c11 extension [-wc11-extensions]?

Tags: c, microcontroller, keil

(Edited) Trying to compile a microcontroller program and have in a page of C code some 44 warnings of this type. Since no lines are flagged in my C file, I assume some sort of problem in an included header file. I have no clue what this warning even means or how it might affect my programs running. Here is the complete warning message:

C:/Users/Binky/AppData/Local/Arm/Packs/Keil/TM4C_DFP/1.1.0/Device/Include/TM4C123\TM4C123GH6PM.h(1251): warning: anonymous unions are a C11 extension [-Wc11-extensions]

That '1251' number gets changed for each warning posted.

I haven't tried anything except Googling the error and not getting anything comprehensible in the way of hits, which were only about 4.I do not know what else I can do if I don't understand what this warning means.

2nd Edit: Although I could not find the file path in explorer - for reasons unknown, there is no AppData after Binky, unless I do a search box query - I came up with the line by just clicking on the warning line in Keil. It brings me to a Union, a new one for each warning.

Comment: Doesn't the error include the filename and line number? It just says that this feature comes from a newer language standard that you haven't enabled. Not a big deal, but you should switch to that newer standard.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". You are supposed to invest some effort before asking here, and to provide a [mre], if applicable. And this looks like a good case for a [mre]. While you're [edit]ing your question, please add the complete error message, as it includes filename and line number of the warnings location.

Comment: The title of your post says you got a warning message. The body of your post says you got an error. Which is it? In any case, it is only a message that your program is using a C 2011 feature. So turn off the message in the compiler, with `-Wno-c11-extensions`.

Comment: I should have perhaps mentioned that I am a relative newbie and have never understood on a deep enough level what Keil's messages mean.  i can always count on them to tell me nothing that i can begin to understand. File name ? I take it it's "TM4C123GH6PM.h" ... Line number 1251 ? That path does not exist in Binky and I almost certainly won't have any independent understanding on why these lines are flagged.

Comment: Please be aware that learning to program includes a lot of researching terms and techniques. Your mind set should be that you understand warning and error messages. The compiler does not want to go on your nerves, instead it tries to help you write good programs. Raise the warning level to the maximum and use a policy of zero warnings and zero errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message includes the path and file name of the source file triggering the error:

```
C:/Users/Binky/AppData/Local/Arm/Packs/Keil/TM4C_DFP/1.1.0/Device/Include/TM4C123\TM4C123GH6PM.h
```

You will not and you should not change such a file, because it belongs to your installation of Keil. It it were one of your own files, you would change it, though.

Instead, add the option `-Wno-c11-extensions` to the compiler call. Visit the preferences of your project for this.

Alternatively you can adjust the version of the C standard, if the preferences allow you. For GCC this is the option `-std=c11`, you might want to research for newer versions. Apparently the chosen standard for your project is pre-C11.

---

**Background:**

The C standard changes certain details between its releases. Before C11 (as of 2011) anonymous unions are not compliant.

The following table summarizes what an anonymous union looks like, shamelessly copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54153832/11294831):

| Code | Anonymous union | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `union { int x; };` | YES | Has no identifier and no tag |
| `union a { int x; };` | NO | Has an identifier `a` |
| `union { int x; } b;` | NO | Has a tag `b` |
| `union a { int x; } b;` | NO | Has an identifier `a` and tag `b` |

Answer (score -1):

Look for the unions and structs embedded into other union structs.

If one does not have the name or the tag - it will be anonymous structure/union

```
struct 
{
    struct 
    {
        int c,d;
    }y;
    //anonymous structure
    struct
    {
        int n,m;
    };
}z;
```